# Странные отступы

Tags: php, html, css

Я новичок в программировании, и я не понимаю откуда отступы у моего сайта. Помогите[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const apiURL= "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=ab8087f04615338cd476b5c8140c648a&page=1";
const api_key= "api_key=ab8087f04615338cd476b5c8140c648a";
const imgpath="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/";
const searchURL="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=ab8087f04615338cd476b5c8140c648a&query=";

const form=document.getElementById('form')
const search=document.getElementById('search')
const main=document.getElementById('main')

// получение фильмов
getmovies(apiURL)
async function getmovies(url){
const res= await fetch(url)
const data= await res.json()
displaygg(data.results)
console.log(data.results);
}
function displaygg(movies){
    main.innerHTML=''
    movies.forEach((movie) => {
        const {title, poster_path, vote_average, overview}= movie
        const moviesel= document.createElement('div')
        moviesel.classList.add('movie')
        moviesel.innerHTML=`
        <img src="${imgpath + poster_path}" alt="${title}" >
        <div class='movie-info'>
            <h3>${title}</h3>
            <span class="${getClassesByRating(vote_average)}">${vote_average}</span>
            <div class='overview'>
            <h3>Overview</h3>
            ${overview}
        </div>
        </div>
        `
        main.appendChild(moviesel)
    });
}
function getClassesByRating(rating){
    if(rating >=8){
        return 'green'
    }else if(rating>=5){
        return 'orange'
    }else{
        return 'red'
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    searchaa= search.value
    if(searchaa && searchaa !=='' ){
        getmovies(searchURL+searchaa)
        searchaa=''
    }else{
        window.localtion.reload()
    }
})
```

```css
:root{
    --primary-color: #9370DB;
    --secondary-color:#4B0082 ;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
.search{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
}
.search::placeholder{
    color: white;
}
.search:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.movie{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.movie img{
    width: 100%;
}

.movie-info{
    color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.movie-info span{
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.movie-info span.green{
    color:lightgreen;
}
.movie-info span.red{
    color:red;
}
.movie-info span.orange{
    color:orange;
}
.overview{
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color:white;
    padding: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(101%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.movie:hover .overview{
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Kms</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" id="search" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>
    </header>
    <main id="main">
        
    </main>
    <script src="js/api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где именно у вас отступы? Можно немного подробнее описать проблему

Comment: Между фильмами справа очень много пустого пространства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот мой ответ. Надеюсь я помог.
Просто добавьте в стилях к блоку (#main) с фильмами одно из этих трёх свойств :

- justify-content: space-around;
- justify-content: center;
- justify-content: space-around;

Надеюсь помог

```js
const apiURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=ab8087f04615338cd476b5c8140c648a&page=1";
const api_key = "api_key=ab8087f04615338cd476b5c8140c648a";
const imgpath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/";
const searchURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=ab8087f04615338cd476b5c8140c648a&query=";

const form = document.getElementById('form')
const search = document.getElementById('search')
const main = document.getElementById('main')

// получение фильмов
getmovies(apiURL)
async function getmovies(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  const data = await res.json()
  displaygg(data.results)
  console.log(data.results);
}

function displaygg(movies) {
  main.innerHTML = ''
  movies.forEach((movie) => {
    const {
      title,
      poster_path,
      vote_average,
      overview
    } = movie
    const moviesel = document.createElement('div')
    moviesel.classList.add('movie')
    moviesel.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${imgpath + poster_path}" alt="${title}" >
        <div class='movie-info'>
            <h3>${title}</h3>
            <span class="${getClassesByRating(vote_average)}">${vote_average}</span>
            <div class='overview'>
            <h3>Overview</h3>
            ${overview}
        </div>
        </div>
        `
    main.appendChild(moviesel)
  });
}

function getClassesByRating(rating) {
  if (rating >= 8) {
    return 'green'
  } else if (rating >= 5) {
    return 'orange'
  } else {
    return 'red'
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  searchaa = search.value
  if (searchaa && searchaa !== '') {
    getmovies(searchURL + searchaa)
    searchaa = ''
  } else {
    window.localtion.reload()
  }
})
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #9370DB;
  --secondary-color: #4B0082;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.search {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

.search::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.search:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*justify-content: space-around;*/
}

.movie {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.movie img {
  width: 100%;
}

.movie-info {
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.movie-info span {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.movie-info span.green {
  color: lightgreen;
}

.movie-info span.red {
  color: red;
}

.movie-info span.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.overview {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(101%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.movie:hover .overview {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Kms</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="search" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
  </header>
  <main id="main">

  </main>
  <script src="js/api.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ответ хорош.(+) Но падежи, род, склонения просто беда.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT понимаю, просто русский мне не родной, но стараюсь как могу))

Comment: Спасибо большое вам всем. Я 5 дней не мог понять где ошибка, а оказывается у меня было .main, а надо было #main.

Comment: Осторожнее следующего раза и можно поставить галочку на ответ?))